# How to know which prediction belongs to which id in classification with neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have attributes, label column and id column in my dataset. Label column consists of 1 and 0. I'm trying to predict a disease for each person but I had to drop id column for training model. I need to use CNN and LSTM to compare results. I need to get prediction probabilities and predicted labels. How do I get predictions for each id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it by creating a dataframe for ids of x_test and dropped id column from x_train and x_test after train_test_split. Then I merged predicted labels, probabilities and ids into a dataframe.